# ANY ARRAYFORMULA INSTEAD OF SUMIF/SUMIFS

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

Hope you're doing well.
My problem is, I need to **SUM** all **BAL** for every ROW in **Column B**.
At this moment I'm currently using `=IF(SUMIF(C$1:W$1,"=BAL",C2:W2)<>0,SUMIF(C$1:W$1,"=BAL",C2:W2),)` for every cell and I've a sheet of 400+ rows and still increasing and this is making the sheet so heavy by the time. So, is there any way to use a arrayformula related formula to get ride of the issue?

Image and Sheet link provided below.

**[image: strong text]**

[To get the sheet for editing](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fn4nuGsT50ZZhA3_H5jLrHynj-sOS48KBxrOHVeUvd0/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with BYROW LAMBDA, like this:

```
=byrow(D2:X,lambda(r,If(SUMIF(D1:X1,"=BAL",r)=0,,SUMIF(D1:X1,"=BAL",r))))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Both of the formulas are useful in it's own way......